# Redirect with end string anchor not working - why not?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect visitors to my monthly Events calendar page (`/optredens/maand/`) to January (`/optredens/maand/2023-01/`), because December (`/optredens/maand/2023-12/`) is empty. Since `/optredens/maand/` defaults to December while the month is going on, I decided to redirect that to January.

First attempt:

```
Redirect 301 /optredens/maand/ https://www.floriskleijne.nl/optredens/maand/2024-01/
```

Yes, I forgot the end-of-string anchor, and yes, I got `/2024/01/2024/01/2024/01/2024/01/2024/01/2024/01/` etc.

Second attempt (including realizing I'd want to redirect the December URL as well):

```
Redirect 301 /optredens/maand/2023-12/$ https://www.floriskleijne.nl/optredens/maand/2024-01/
Redirect 301 /optredens/maand/$         https://www.floriskleijne.nl/optredens/maand/2024-01/
```

With anchors, this did nothing at all.

Removing the anchor from the December URL, got that particular redirect to work:

```
Redirect 301 /optredens/maand/2023-12/ https://www.floriskleijne.nl/optredens/maand/2024-01/
Redirect 301 /optredens/maand/$        https://www.floriskleijne.nl/optredens/maand/2024-01/
```

But the `/optredens/maand/` URL does not get redirected at all.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Ah. RedirectMatch is the way to get it to process RegEx. I had no idea (obviously)!